# Upload image file to remote server Android PhP

Tags: php, android, file-upload, remote-server

I am working on an android app where i need to upload a user's image file to a remote server. When I run the php script using localhost as my server, the image uploads successfully. However when I try to upload the same file using the same code to my remote server, it does not upload. Here is the php script `

```
$file_path = "prof_pics/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

?>`

I am attempting to upload the file from the device to the `/var/www/prof_pics/` directory that I created. I have tried both the previous way and using `/var/www/prof_pics/` instead of just `prof_pics/`  in the php code to try to upload. My android app sends me the Log message I have written when the upload is successful ("Image Upload Complete"). However when I attempt to search the server for the image using `sudo find / -name '4718256.98529.png'`. There are no results returned. How can it be that

1. The image file uploads successfully when I am using localhost
2. When using the appropriately modified version of the same php script, does not upload successfully.
3. The response from the server is 200, meaning the file was uploaded.
4. If the program is correct and the file was uploaded, i cannot find the file in the appropriate location.

Comment: have you tried to look if the file is there with filezilla or the file manager that your host give you??

Comment: @geekCode I have not. I am unsure if I have a file manager. I am using Google Cloud SQL. Also, shouldnt the result turn up in the search if it was indeed there?

Comment: @superuserdo this could be a permission issue try to upload to the same current directory so just the filename and omit the path. you might need to change permission `chmod 0777 prof_pics`

Comment: @meda i tried uploading to home directory and still didnt work. I also tried chmod...where else could this file be being uploaded to?

Comment: Is this your full code , i suggest you to log events and errors into a file. I dont think you can rely on the http 200 code

Comment: @meda yes it is my full code for uploading to the server php.

Comment: You'll get a 200 code from the server even if PHP hits an error, so that doesn't mean anything. You need to return all the output from the PHP script and check for a printed error.

Comment: @BrianDeWolff Im going to conclude that meda's answer is what worked. I performed the command and attempted to upload but it did not show up. However I attempted a few minutes later and the file was on there. I have tested around 20 times after and it works everytime now with the same code.